# How can I create a button in Codea

Tags: lua, codea

So I am new to lua and I am curious how to make buttons.
P.S. I work with Codea engine so the fn tag doesn’t work.
I looked everywhere but I can’t find a good tutorial.

Comment: there are no buttons in Lua so I edited your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codea doesn't seem to provide buttons. But you can draw and you can process touch input. So you have all that is necessary to create your own buttons.

Draw a button, then check wether the screen was touched inside the buttons boundaries.

https://codea.io/reference/

and especially

https://codea.io/reference/Graphics.html

https://codea.io/reference/Touch.html

If you'd simply google "Codea button" you would find several examples...

Comment: ok thanks have a good day :)